# SQL server Partitioned table and entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Can we get the benefits of the partitioning of a SQL server 2010 table when we use entity framework as the data layer?
The table will have 10 000 records per day and it will be partitioned by the date created (Ex :- Older than 30 days and new)

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What is your situation, what is the DB used for, how large, what are you partitioning on, how big are the partitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not very skilled in SQL Server so perhaps I'm wrong but I believe that table partitioning should be transparent to queries (if we are talking about automatic partition function defined in the table) - it means that common queries should still work and even have better performance if partitioning is configured correctly. So in case of database-frist design, EF should not have any problem with this because it still works with single logical table. If you mean manual partitioning by creating new table each month then it is a big probrem with EF and you will need stored procedures to access that tables.

Comment: " If you mean manual partitioning by creating new table each month" what this means ?Is It means creating new partition or creating new table for every month?

Comment: New table without any partitioning function.